# Error in SQL syntax when setting up a password

Tags: mysql

i don't know what is the problem here?

http://shrani.si/f/1y/rX/1GAMFf7B/untitled.jpg

Comment: you're not at the mysql prompt at the point you make that query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not press enter after `mysql -u root` instead type `\c` to cancel it
and then on new promp  write your new fresh update query.

```
mysql> mysql -u root \c
mysql> update user set password = PASSWORD('value') where user = 'root';
```

Comment: now i get "no database selected" ??

Comment: I managed to make it work, thanx guys

Comment: You are welcome @Ruzbeh Irani :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the user name (root) in quotes - look like MySQL may be thinking that it is a column rather than a string value

Answer (score 0):

See the error message? It's trying with all its might to tell you something. You have, indeed, an error in your SQL syntax: `mysql root -u` is not valid SQL.

In other words, you are mixing the mysql client invocation with a MySQL query. In the mysql client, everything up to a `;` is considered one query (end of line is not a command separator). Therefore, the server is trying to make sense of this MySQL query:

```
mysql root -u UPDATE mysql.user SET password='(...etc)'
```

which is, as the error message helpfully explains, invalid SQL.

Running only the query that starts with `UPDATE` should be OK.